# R: Reshape data to create a multiline-plot from different variables

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have to create a plot with different lines from different variables.

One the y-axis:

```
> a1
[1]   7  10  12  19  30  45  68 104 151 214 279 362 425 467 487 493 498 500
> a2
[1]   7  11  20  33  59  94 151 244 334 425 483 500
> a3
[1]   7  17  35  77 150 241 361 450 488 500
> a4
[1]   7  20  50 129 292 441 498 500
> a5
[1]   7  22  68 191 382 493 500
```

On the x-axis:

```
> b1
[1] 18
> b2
[1] 12
> b3
[1] 12
> b4
[1] 10
> b5
[1] 8
```

a1 and b1 should be one line, a2 and b2 another and so on.

How can I fit the data to the same scale?

How can I generate a plot in which all lines are included?

Right now, the single plots look like this: [image: Example 1][image: Example 2]
The code used for the plots looks like this:

```
plot(a1, type="l",col="red",xlim=c(1,b1),main="Example1", xlab="x", ylab = "y")
plot(a2,type="l",col="blue",xlim=c(1,b2),main="Example2", xlab="x", ylab = "y")
```

The requestet dput():

```
> dput(a1)
c(6, 8, 12, 20, 34, 54, 80, 110, 159, 214, 281, 345, 402, 447, 479, 492, 494, 498, 500)
> dput(b1)
19L
> dput(a2)
c(6, 12, 24, 42, 76, 127, 209, 306, 375, 441, 476, 495, 499,  499, 500)
> dput(b2)
15L
```

As you can probably tell, I am very new to using R.

Comment: Hi! What kind of result are you looking for? If you plot one line with one axe costant, you'd end up with a simple straight line. Is that correct with you?

Comment: I just edited my original question, to give you an example on how my single plots look right now.

Comment: Please post the output of `dput` on your data, rather than a printout. What code got you those plots? And are you looking to translate this into a `ggplot` solution, since you included that tag?

Comment: Just did that. I found some solutions using ggplot, I tried it, but I wasn´t able to put my data into a dataframe.

Comment: I'm confused. What are `b1` and `b2`? Those just seem to be single numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a problem of getting data in shape in order to plot it. I'm a little confused by what the data is exactly that you're working with, i.e. what `b1`, `b2`, etc. are. But with the `a1` and `a2` you posted (and whatever similar vectors you have), you should get everything into a data frame. The fact that these vectors are of different lengths doesn't matter because `ggplot` expects long-shaped data anyway. That is, as far as I can tell, `a1` and `a2` contain different sets of measurements of the same sort of thing (stock values, size of an organism, probability of some outcome, etc); therefore, in the tidy-data paradigm, they should be different groups of the same variable.

So I first make a data frame/tibble of each set of data, giving them an `x` that's just integers from 1 to whatever is the length of its `a` vector, then give it a group marker so I can keep each set of measurements straight. Then I bind that into a single data frame.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(
  a = c(6, 8, 12, 20, 34, 54, 80, 110, 159, 214, 281, 345, 402, 447, 479, 492, 494, 498, 500),
  x = 1:length(a),
  group = 1
)
df2 <- tibble(
  a = c(6, 12, 24, 42, 76, 127, 209, 306, 375, 441, 476, 495, 499,  499, 500),
  x = 1:length(a),
  group = 2
)
df <- bind_rows(df1, df2)
df
#> # A tibble: 34 x 3
#>        a     x group
#>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#>  1     6     1     1
#>  2     8     2     1
#>  3    12     3     1
#>  4    20     4     1
#>  5    34     5     1
#>  6    54     6     1
#>  7    80     7     1
#>  8   110     8     1
#>  9   159     9     1
#> 10   214    10     1
#> # ... with 24 more rows
```

The `ggplot` way of doing things is to map variables onto aesthetics such as color. If you find yourself making multiple geoms that serve essentially the same purpose (like a `geom_line` for each of a set of observations), you probably need to reshape your data.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = a, color = as.factor(group), group = as.factor(group))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

This will scale for however many sets of observations you have—create smaller data frames for each `a*`, mark them as a group, and bind them all together.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

As with many things `ggplot`, there are a lot of ways to do this.  I think the easiest would be to save all your vectors in one data.frame/tibble and then refer to the columns in individual `geom_line` calls.  In the example below I made each line a different color just to more easily distinguish between the two.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(a1 = c(1, 2 ,3, 4, 5), b1 = c(20), a2 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9), b2 = c(30))

ggplot(data = data) +
 geom_line(aes(x = a1, y = b1), color = "blue") +
 geom_line(aes(x = a2, y = b2), color = "red")
```

Or with different length data:

```
library(tidyverse)

data_1 <- tibble(a1 = c(1, 2 ,3, 4, 5), b1 = c(20)) 

data_2 <- tibble(a2 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), b2 = c(30))

ggplot() +
 geom_line(data = data_1, aes(x = a1, y = b1), color = "blue") +
 geom_line(data = data_2, aes(x = a2, y = b2), color = "red")
```

Comment: I just tried your code, I got an error due to the different collumn lengths.

Comment: The code as is works (the column lengths are not different).  But, if _you're_ data has different lengths, then you'd need to put them in different data sets.  I'll edit it to show you.